# Network data transfer seems to hang after a minute or so: troubleshoot and/or fix

Tags: wi-fi, networking

My android phone on my home wifi acts like data is not transferring. The cable modem is fine (laptop works). The problem seems to be with the phone. On the phone I turn wifi off, then back on, and I get another minute or so of seemingly normal operation, then it hangs up again.  When wifi is off, everything works fine over cell data. Battery usage and other indicators show that everything is behaving.

1. I can't find a definitive test that shows the moment it breaks every time. It's just apps starting to hang up.
2. The breakage could be subtle, like just name resolution (DNS) breaking. I can't really tell.
3. Could it be some permissions problem, like background apps or something?
4. Where would I search for answers on this?
5. Would a factory reset help? If it wouldn't help, I'd hate to do it of course.
6. Are there tools that would help troubleshoot this?

It's a Samsung Galaxy S9+.

Comment: What happens if you start a download that requires more time than the time before Wifi stops working?

Comment: @Robert It's hard to achieve that on my phone. Downloads happen quick when they work. Thanks for giving this some thought.

Comment: If your cable connection has a data flat just download one of the various Linux DVD images - preferable from a mirror that is a bit slow.

Comment: @Robert    Let me check the size of my microSD...